# Java フィルタ内(doFilter)で、チェーン先のクラス名取得方法

Tags: java, spring-boot

Java フィルタ内(doFilter)で、チェーン先のクラス名を取得したいのですが、取得する方法はありますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

サーブレットフィルタの話でしょうか。

サーブレットフィルタからchain.doFilter(request,response)を実行して起動するサーブレットは直接取得できませんが、フィルタ定義の設定内容でしたら、サーブレットコンテキストから取得は可能です。

```
ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();
FilterRegistration filterRegistration = context.getFilterRegistration("sampleFilter");
Collection<String> servletNameMappings = filterRegistration.getServletNameMappings();
Collection<String> urlPatternMappings = filterRegistration.getUrlPatternMappings();
```

```

Comment: サーブレットフィルタの話で大丈夫です。チェーン先のクラス名を取得するのは不可能ということでしょうか？